# Fetching Credentials in PHP

Tags: php, laravel, twilio, multi-tenant

I am working on a Laravel application which sends out SMS, and has several other integrations. The integrations are per company listed in the organization table. I have created a table of integrations and linked those with relationships to the organizations table.

Is there a better way to do this? Refactor somehow? I was thinking of using a class that extends the Twilio client class, and then putting the credentials in there. So it would be just simple to call TwilioClient and thats it. On the backend (class) it would do all the heavy lifting of checking the db and getting the credentials.

Right now this is what I have.

```
    public function test()
    {
        $integration = Integration::where('provider', '=', 'Twilio')->first();
        $credentials = $integration->credentials;
        $client = new Client($credentials['sid'], $credentials['token']);
        $s = $client->lookups->v1->phoneNumbers("+14801234567")->fetch(
              ["addons" => ["ekata_reverse_phone"]]);
        return $s->addOns;
    }
```

Ideally I would like to avoid putting this code in each area that has an integration. Twilio is just an example. It could be AWS, or Azure, or any other PHP/REST/Graph integration, etc.

```
$integration = Integration::where('provider', '=', 'Twilio')->first();
        $credentials = $integration->credentials;
        $client = new Client($credentials['sid'], $credentials['token']);
```

It would be great to be able to call something like:

```
$client = new IntegrationClient('Twilio');
```

From there is would do all of the work on the backend.

I appreciate the patience. I am still learning on this and any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've not done a whole lot with multi-tenancy before. That said, I don't see anything in your current code that is tenant specific. I use Twilio in a current project and use dependency injection to provide my controller the client. I then use the AppServiceProvider to bind an instance of the Twilio Client to an instantiated version with my credentials; `$this->bind(Client::class, new Client($credentials['sid'], $credentials['token']));`. This also makes your code more testable (if you're doing that). Hope I didn't go too deep. Happy to provide an answer with a working version of the above.

Comment: @James thank you for that information. I am using the Stancl Tenancy package. But once the tenant is authenticated, that tenant has multiple clients (organizations) that need their own separate credentials for a variety of integrations that they enable.

Comment: I will modify my original post to show additional info.

Comment: You're still newing up concrete classes which is fine if that's what you want to do. I'd argue that each class already knows what integration it wants. I'd use conditional binding and inject a configured client. I can give an example if you want?

Comment: @James If you could give me an example, I would greatly appreciate it. I have been watching so many videos online and reading so much but nothing that really digs into how/why you would use a certain method vs another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following on from our comments.

I feel like each class you are using an integration in already explicitly knows which integration it wants; it just needs one that is configured for your tenant.

The way I typically do this (and have done with Twilio) is to bind instances of the Twilio Client to an instantiated version of the client with credentials and all.

The way I would see this working in your code would be like so:

```
// AppServiceProvider.php

// In your boot function

$this->app->bind(Client::class, function () {
    $integration = Integration::where('provider', 'Twilio')->first();
    $credentials = $integration->credentials;
    new Client($credentials['sid'], $credentials['token']));
});
```

Now in your class that needs to use Twilio:

```
private $client;

public function __construct(Client $client)
{
    $this->client = $client;
}

public function test()
{
    $s = $this->client->lookups->v1->phoneNumbers("+14801234567")->fetch(
         ["addons" => ["ekata_reverse_phone"]]
    );
    return $s->addOns;
}
```

The binding in your AppServiceProvider will tell the Laravel container that whenever a class is asking for the Twilio client, then execute that callback and provide the result.
This means that your class receives an instantiated version of the client rather than an unconfigured one.

Comment: Seeing this printed out in the context of what I needed makes so much more sense now.  I will test with this a bit. Thank you so much for this.